# Notificaciones locales para moviles con phonegap

Tags: javascript, phonegap, android-notifications, notificaciones

Estoy intentando crear notificaciones locales para móviles con la app móvil que estoy desarrollando y no hay manera de que funcione.

Estoy utilizando el plugin "cordova-plugin-local-notification", lo implemento pero nada, no funciona. Estoy primero intentando que funcione esto:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
   text: "Wake up!",
   every: 30 // every 30 minutes
});
```

Por ejemplo, que se repita cada 30 minutos, pero nada no funciona.

Pongo este trozo de código en el "device ready" pero no hace nada.

Yo lo que quiero es que al pulsar un botón simplemente muestre o cree la notificación, pero no lo logro.

Estaba probando las notificaciones repetitivas para ver si de este modo... Pero tampoco.

Instalo el plugin pero después miro en el config.xml de phonegap y no aparece

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" />
```

Esto lo he puesto a mano al final del archivo config.xml.

Saludos.

Comment: Te da algún tipo de error?

Comment: Que va. No hace nada. Ni errores, ni funcionamiento ni nada

Comment: Haz probado con el código de ejemplo del plugin? https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: Sí. Y tampoco me funciona.